# Visual Studio 2013 can't start after connecting to my workstation using RDP

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7, remote-desktop

After each time I connect to my workstation using Remote Desktop (when I have to work from home or elsewhere in the office) I cannot start Visual Studio 2013. I get a message saying :

> A problem occurred when loading the Microsoft Visual Studio menu. To fix this problem, run 'devenv.exe /resetsettings' from the command prompt. Note: this command resets your environment settings.

Running devenv.exe /resetsettings gives me the same message.
"Run as admin" gives me the same error.

To fix the problem I have to reboot my PC. The problem is I have to connect remotely at least 3-4 times a week. Rebooting my PC every time is getting annoying.

Any clues?

I'm running Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: have you fixed that? i get the same thing here even with the file explorer

Comment: Nothing yet. I found that sometimes I can just kill explorer.exe, restart it and after that VS2013 starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your system PATH variable is under 2048 characters.

See [Jonathan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/872710) to ["After remote desktop, target PC some shortcuts don't work, possibly loses %windir%"](https://superuser.com/questions/867950/after-remote-desktop-target-pc-some-shortcuts-dont-work-possibly-loses-windi).

I have the same problem, with the same setup and symptoms, it appears to be related to the PATH variable being too long. I found that my PATH was 2072 characters and after removing unnecessary entries I was able to run Visual Studio and others again without restarting.